# Theme vs Extension - What is the the correct way to remove a conflict? Magento 2 - Port Theme vs Mirasvit Layered Navigation

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, porto-theme, mirasvit

I am using Magento 2 with the Porto Theme and the Mirasvit Layered Navigation Extension. Currently I am getting an error because the Mirasvit Layered Extension is expecting a **Mirasvit\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection** but instead a **Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor** is being returned.

```
TypeError: Mirasvit\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter::getProductCollection(): Return value must be of type Mirasvit\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection, Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor returned
```

Apolgies for this perhaps basic question but what is the correct approach to deactivate the themes attempt to handle the layered navigation so that the extension is used instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that you have two extensions for the Layered Navigation: the first one is Mirasvit_LayeredNavigation, and the second one is Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation (which is included with the theme). If you want to use Mirasvit_LayeredNavigation, you should disable the Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation extension.